# Magento 2 - No PayPal Pro option in admin

Tags: magento, paypal

I've setup my store using Magento 2.1.5 and have come to the point of setting up the payment methods. I wanted to use PayPal Pro so the user stays on the site during checkout (no SSL as of yet but will be installing one).

On the Store > Configuration > Sales > Payment Methods page I only get 'PayPal Express Checkout' and no Pro option.

I've noticed Braintree by PayPal but would rather use PayPal Pro for now.

Is there something I'm missing??

Cheers,

Nick

Answer (score 4):

its quite well hidden isnt it!  You need to click the blue link under the main paypal options which says 'OTHER PAYPAL PAYMENT SOLUTIONS', that's where you'll find Paypal Pro[image]

Comment: yay! so there you are! :-D

Comment: Just a note, that this option applies to the UK only: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/graphql/payment-methods/hosted-pro.html